# full screen issue in html while redirect page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

When I am putting below code for full screen but when I redirect another page full screen  is not working .how can do this when redirect full screen is not close.My full screen code is here.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function toggleFullScreen() {
            if ((document.fullScreenElement && document.fullScreenElement !== null) || (!document.mozFullScreen && !document.webkitIsFullScreen)) {
                if (document.documentElement.requestFullScreen) {
                    document.documentElement.requestFullScreen();
                } else if (document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen) {
                    document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen();
                } else if (document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
                    document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullScreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
                }
            } else {
                if (document.cancelFullScreen) {
                    document.cancelFullScreen();
                } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
                    document.mozCancelFullScreen();
                } else if (document.webkitCancelFullScreen) {
                    document.webkitCancelFullScreen();
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
```

please help me.

Comment: Are you sure the function is running? Do you get any console errors? What actually happens?

Comment: yes ..WHY ..what happen.?

Comment: This question could use some help. Perhaps you should read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and apply it. Even putting your problem into [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) would help you, at least, if not us.

Comment: Check [my answer to a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31405626/javascript-full-screen/31408599#31408599). The issue is that there are two full screen modes: the full screen that you are setting with JavaScript is only applied to the document/element and not to the browser window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[[Extracted from my own answer to a similar question]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31405626/javascript-full-screen/31408599#31408599):

This issue happens because there are two different full screen modes:

- [One applied to elements/documents](https://fullscreen.spec.whatwg.org/#fullscreen-element) that you trigger using JavaScript (the one you are using with the API). This fullscreen is lost when the page reloads or when you browse to a different page.
- Another native to the browser that is set by the user with F11 (applied to the browser itself, and not to the page/document: if you reload or browse to a different site, the browser will continue in fullscreen mode).

---

**[For your particular case]**:

You are using the [Fullscreen API](https://fullscreen.spec.whatwg.org/), so when you navigate to a different page the full screen is lost (because it applies to that particular document that is left behind).

One possible solution would be to have an `iframe` that occupies the whole size of the screen, and apply the full screen to the document that contains it. That way, the user will move within the `iframe` that will be in a full-screen document.

Something like this (you will need to copy this code into your own file as due to security reasons, frames are not allowed in the code snippets):

```js
function toggleFullScreen() {
  
  // hide the button
  document.getElementById("mybutton").style.display = "none";
  
  // your content
  if ((document.fullScreenElement && document.fullScreenElement !== null) || (!document.mozFullScreen && !document.webkitIsFullScreen)) {
    if (document.documentElement.requestFullScreen) {
      document.documentElement.requestFullScreen();
    } else if (document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen) {
      document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen();
    } else if (document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
      document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullScreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
    }
  } else {
    if (document.cancelFullScreen) {
      document.cancelFullScreen();
    } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
      document.mozCancelFullScreen();
    } else if (document.webkitCancelFullScreen) {
      document.webkitCancelFullScreen();
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#mybutton { z-index:2; position:absolute; }
iframe { z-index:1; position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width:100%; height:100%; }
```

```html
<button id="mybutton" onclick="toggleFullScreen()">Full Screen</button>
<iframe src="http://stackoverflow.com"></iframe>
```